# java: use dedicated folder for storing libraries?

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans, jstl

i'm using netbeans and When i create a new **Java Web** >> **Web Application** there is an option to **use dedicated folder for storing libraries**

I'm wondering what's the difference if i check/uncheck it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check the box then all your libs will be copied onto that folder (for the project) instead of just referencing them from your file system. This can be useful if you're gonna import your project in a repository. However the size of the folder will increase greatly. I don't recommend using this option unless there's no practical way of sending those libs to your collaborators.

Comment: so does that mean it is better to send those libs independently to the other "people" and let them do the linking themselves?

Comment: Well, if they are near you (maybe in your office) I think an USB media is way faster than your connection if you're using, say, GitHub. It's up to you anyways.

Comment: ok so am i right to say the benefit gained is small file size at the cost of "set-up" time?

Answer (score 3):

By checking the option of using dedicated folder, all jar dependencies stored in the lib folder underneath your project are automatically copied to the distribution folder at build time.You can guarantee to take your project to any machine and run the build with Ant (or NetBeans).